# AWK command not working in linux but works in mac

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, syntax-error

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong here? It seems to work on my mac shell but does not work on linux box it seems. Looks like different version of awk? I want to make sure my code works on the linux version.

```
echo -e "${group_values_with_counts}" | awk '$1>='${value2}' { print "{\"count\":\""$1"\",\"type\":\""$2"\"}" }'


21:19:41 awk: $1>= { print "{\"count\":\""$1"\",\"type\":\""$2"\"}" }
21:19:41 awk:      ^ syntax error
```

Comment: Seems like `${value2}` is empty. Are you sure the variable is set to the same value on both systems?

Comment: Where is value2 getting set? It seems to be empty by the time it's passed to awk, so the preceding code would be useful to track down the error.

Comment: That's just a quoting problem. It will explode in any bash shell, depending on the content of the variables

Comment: Can you add the output from `echo -e "${group_values_with_counts}"` to your question?

Comment: PS: I'm not sure if the vanilla bash-3.x on mac supports `echo -e`. check `help echo` when in doubt

Comment: It is not the quoting problem. It works well in my mac bash

Comment: Yes, it definitely IS the quoting problem. The problem will become visible based on whether or not `$value2` is populated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to pass the value of a shell variable into awk the wrong way and using a non-portable echo. The right way (assuming value2 doesn't contain any backslashes) is:

```
printf '%s\n' "$group_values_with_counts" |
awk -v value2="$value2" '$1>=value2{ print "{\"count\":\""$1"\",\"type\":\""$2"\"}" }'
```

If value2 can contains backslashes and you want them treated literally (e.g. you do not want `\t` converted to a tab character) then you need to pass it in using ENVIRON or ARGV. See http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24.